# Wordpress admin dashboard works very slow with many pages

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that it is working perfectly with a bunch of posts and pages.

I have recently started a process to migrate the contents from another website and this has added ~16,000 pages and ~100,000 posts to the site.

Now, in the admin dashboard, when <strike>I go to the page list or</strike> I try to edit a page, it takes ages to load or stops loading because the timeout is fired. This is not happening with the posts, I can open the post list and edit any without issues. The frontend is working fine.

I'm starting to believe that Wordpress might not be able to manage that quantity of pages. Is there a solution to this? Replace Wordpress with another CMS like Drupal or Joomla is my latest option.

I also tried to tune mySQL, disable all the plugins (I only have a few), etc. with no luck at all.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I found out the reason of this slowness. When editing a page, Wordpress displays a dropdown list to select a parent page. This list is populated with every single page available on the site (ugh) and this is causing the huge load times. If I "tell" Wordpress to not show this dropdown list (via functions.php or editing the core), everything goes back to normal.